# Can call stack for kernel and/or userspace be generated using lttng? If so, how?

Tags: profiling, stack-trace, lttng

My aim is to generate call stack and hence flamegraph using lttng. I looked into the [documentaion](http://lttng.org/docs/v2.9/) but it doesn't say anything about call stack. Then this stackoverflow question seems to have got callstack. But upon reconstructing the steps I couldn't get any call stack data. I also have a doubt that whether the call stack can be geerated only for the instrumented userspace programs or for kernelspace as well. Am I missing something? [Tracecompass view of my trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22tCz.png)

Answer (score 1):

To use the Call Stack view of Trace Compass, you have to do the following steps in addition of the regular LTTng-UST session configuration:

1. Compile your application with the GCC options `-g -finstrument-functions`
2. Enable the `vpid`, `vtid`, and `procname` LTTng userspace contexts
3. Preload the `liblttng-ust-cyg-profile.so`

See the [Trace Compass documentation](http://archive.eclipse.org/tracecompass/doc/stable/org.eclipse.tracecompass.doc.user/LTTng-UST-Analyses.html#Call_Stack_View) for more details

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. What if I'm not bothered about userspace application but only the kernel modules and functions. Does this give the kernel functions in the flamegraph too?

Comment: No, this technique gathers the userspace callstack and not the kernel space callstack. This feature is planned but not ready yet.